# Mat declaration in openCV android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I tried to create a simple Mat in openCV for android but it keep showing error at the init of the Mat

```
public Mat mdigits;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tmpViewer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMain);
        tmpViewer.setText("LOL");

        mdigits.create(10,10,CvType.CV_8UC1);

　　　　　　　Mat target = new Mat(10,10,CvType.CV_8UC1);
    }
```

Both approaches yield the same error.
I'm using openCVLib300

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I thought you had to some kind of initialization for opencv native libs, like OpenCVLoader.initAsync(...) or OpenCVLoader.initDebug().

Comment: It throws a NULL exception in Mat native method aka the constructor

Comment: you will have to move your code **out of** onCreate(), the native c++ so's are not loaded yet.